# WSO2 API manager Synapse-HttpComponents-NIO get a 404 when curl get 200

Tags: apache, wso2, apache-synapse, wso2-api-manager

I'm calling a PHP API located on the same host of the API manager using a published API.
The client application is SoapUI or curl.

I issue the call and it gets passed to the httpd server that return:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer Q7Eb8k6oUBe6O4nP10sEgzZREMMa" --url "http://10.1.1.141:8280/accident/v1/v1/accident.json"

10.1.1.141 - - [07/Feb/2013:12:41:41 +0100] "GET http://apman2.cortile.cloudlabcsi.local/restTest.php/v1/accident.json HTTP/1.1" 404 514 "-" "Synapse-HttpComponents-NIO"

curl http://apman2.cortile.cloudlabcsi.local/restTest.php/v1/accident.json

10.1.1.157 - - [07/Feb/2013:12:41:36 +0100] "GET /restTest.php/v1/accident.json HTTP/1.1" 200 120 "-" "curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.13.1.0 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.2.2"
```

Obviously The first is a call to the final API that WSO2 publishes with its own publish URL so the resulting call is made by Synapse-HttpComponents-NIO: curl call API-Manager and it uses Synapse-HttpComponents-NIO to call the PHP API.
The second is the same call issued directly from curl to the PHP API.
Logs are from HTTPD.

It's evident that the httpd receives the call
I cannot understand why Synapse-HttpComponents-NIO client get a 404 whils curl get the correct results.
Thanks
Luca